# Which one has better performance , CSS gradient or background image?

Tags: html, css

I want to know which one uses CPU and RAM more efficiently?

using an image file and repeating:

```
background:url(../images/livebg/02a.jpg) repeat-x
```

or using CSS webkit background gradient:

```
background : -moz-linear-gradient(50% 100% 90deg,rgba(0, 111, 122, 1) 0%,rgba(0, 68, 75, 1) 100%);
background : -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 111, 122, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 68, 75, 1) 100%); 
background : -webkit-gradient(linear,50% 100% ,50% 0% ,color-stop(0,rgba(0, 111, 122, 1) ),color-stop(1,rgba(0, 68, 75, 1) ));  
background : -o-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 111, 122, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 68, 75, 1) 100%);
```

Image size is 1x40 pixel.

Answer (score 4):

There is no real difference. Current browser engines all render the gradient internally as an image and then use that during actual page rendering. It's possible that a re-render is triggered when resizing the containing elements, but that's negligible.

The question reeks of premature micro-optimization. Page rendering speeds are rarely relevant, compared to the much larger overheads of network traffic and roundtrips. As such, it is definitely a better idea to use the CSS gradients, as it eliminates a roundtrip (although you should embed a 40 pixel image as a data-URL anyway for the exact same reason).

Answer (score 3):

CSS gradient will not use your bandwidth but would use your CPU and ram more than background image.

And on the other hand, background image will use your majority bandwidth compared to gradients. So it is trade off.

I would suggest CSS gradients if you can work with that because if your image is a large chunk of data it could clog your application.

Optimal usage would be using CSS gradients and using image as fall back for unsupported browsers.

Comment: well but background-image is supported more  across browsers

Comment: @NaeemShaikh only relevant for [ancient IE versions](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients).

Comment: Yes. But gradients are not far behind. May be IE8 would be the lower edge of support. but you can always use modernizer and use image as fall back.

Comment: @AngularHarsh. it was just a suggestion. +1 from me

Answer (score 2):

Both works fine. but its better to use gradients since images takes more time to load than gradients.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Jquery UI themes that use repeated 1 pixel wide images that are repeated as backgrounds.  A bit of CSS trickery and changed them all to gradients, the performance improvement was very noticeable.

Not sure about a wider image performance, however the gradients look far sharper and modern.